# Visual Studio 2013 Professional linker errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker

I really want to use Visual Studio Professional's debugger to take a look at a segmentation fault I encountered in my program. However, the IDE would not compile even a simple program such as this:

```
// test_aug.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     cout << "Test" ; 
     return 0;
}
```

It keeps throwing the error "error LNK1104: cannot open file 'gdi32.lib'. 
The thing is I don't want to fix this one linking error just to keep getting more for different libraries (I have also seen it for different libraries).

Can someone please tell me how to fix this error in general so I will not encounter it anymore, and can move on to ACTUALLY DEBUGGING.

Comment: You failed the basic Hello World test.  Somebody could write a lengthy check-list of things that could have gone wrong when you installed VS but that's just going to look like a bunch of gobbledegook to you.  Basic approach is to get your machine stable, try another one if possible, spin the re-install wheel of fortune.

Answer (score 1):

If the linker cannot find that library check for its existence and/or [set the path to find it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe.aspx) into **additional library directories**.

The linking phase won't go on without solving that error first.

Other two thoughts:

- gd123.lib sounds wrong, I believe you wanted to use **gdi32.lib**. Make sure the name is right
- make sure that is included into the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) (express editions don't include it)

Comment: When I go to the directories to set paths it says that its deprecated.

Comment: Should I just reinstall?

Comment: gdi32.lib is deprecated? Are you sure? Anyway the compiler should include that itself, remove it

Comment: When I go to tools > options > projects and solutions > vc++ directories, thats when I get the message "VC++ Directories editing in Tools > Options has been deprecated. VC++ Directories are now available as a user property sheet that is added by default to all projects."

Comment: Either remove that library (it should be automatically linked for win32/64 apps) or go into the project settings and add the right path to the linker additional directories

Comment: Ok. Im looking at the property pages now. Hopefully I can figure this out. Its just so frustrating. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh my... It says that its there! Under Property pages > linker > additional dependencies. I am not sure why the problem persists...

Comment: When everything else fails.. do a build clean and rebuild all :)